# Django: How to create enum of classes to define choices

Tags: python, django, enums

How to subclass models.Choices to define enum of classes?

The following code raises TypeError:

```
from django.db.models import Choices

class DataTypes(type, Choices):
    CHAR = str, _('Short string')
    INTEGER = int, _('Integer')
```

The error message:

```
dynamic_attributes = {k for c in enum_class.mro()
TypeError: descriptor 'mro' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

UPDATE:

When no mixin is used, then the error does not appear. But all the same, the values of the members are not converted correctly into the required data type.

```
class DataTypes(Choices):
    CHAR = str, _('Short string')
    INTEGER = int, _('Integer')
```

Test:

```
str in (DataTypes.CHAR, DataTypes.INTEGER) # False
```

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Django 3.1

Comment: This is a consequence of the `Enum` class itself: A new Enum class must have one base Enum class, up to one concrete data type. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing).

Comment: I would advice to just use `Choices`, and thus not type it.

Comment: For `object` it does not work either.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem When no mixin is used (only 'Choices'), then the error does not appear. But all the same, the values of the members are not converted correctly into the required data type. I will add this note to my question.

Comment: hold on, but the question is, how will you store these types? You can not stor Python types in a database. You need something that is storable, like a string/int/...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You can store the import path to any class and use a descriptor to parse a class (full Python object). Just like FileField.

Comment: yes, but than you should not use the types, then you should use some wrapping mechanism to convert from/to the item you store in database, and the one you use.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, that what I did it in 'field.get_prep_value()' and 'field.from_db_value()' methods. I will add the custom field code if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Willem Van Onsem's opinion in the comments. I think it is impossible to use `models.Choices` for such data type as classes. So I tried to find a different approach with the ability to extend other classes.

Defining labels for choices (as Django Choices does) is also implemented.

```
def _is_dunder(name):
    """
    Stolen liberally from 'aenum'.

    Returns True if a __dunder__ name, False otherwise.
    """
    return (len(name) > 4 and
            name[:2] == name[-2:] == '__' and
            name[2] != '_' and
            name[-3] != '_')


class ChoicesMeta(type):

    def __new__(mcs, cls, bases, attrs):
        # ignore any keys listed in _ignore_
        ignore = attrs.setdefault('_ignore_', [])
        ignore.append('_ignore_')

        # save constant names into list.
        names = [k for k in attrs if not(_is_dunder(k) or k in ignore)]

        # save constant labels into list.
        labels = []
        for k in names:
            value = attrs[k]
            if (
                isinstance(value, (list, tuple)) and
                len(value) > 1 and
                isinstance(value[-1], (Promise, str))
            ):
                value, label = value
            else:
                label = k.replace('_', ' ').title()
            labels.append(label)
            attrs[k] = value

        new_cls = super().__new__(mcs, cls, bases, attrs)
        new_cls.local_names = names
        new_cls.local_labels = labels
        return new_cls

    @property
    def names(cls):
        names = []
        for c in reversed(cls.__mro__):
            names.extend(getattr(c, 'local_names', []))
        return list(dict.fromkeys(names))

    @property
    def choices(cls):
        empty = [(None, cls.__empty__)] if hasattr(cls, '__empty__') else []
        return empty + [(getattr(cls, name), cls.labels[i]) for i, name in enumerate(cls.names)]

    @property
    def labels(cls):
        labels = []
        for c in reversed(cls.__mro__):
            labels.extend(getattr(c, 'local_labels', []))
        return list(dict.fromkeys(labels))


class Choices(metaclass=ChoicesMeta):
    pass
```

Now you can create your Choices class and also subclass it:

```
class DataTypes(Choices):
    CHAR = str, _('Short string')
    INTEGER = int


class OtherTypes(DataTypes):
    BOOLEAN = bool, _('Boolean (Either True or False)')
    FLOAT = float, _('Floating point number')
```

Tests:

```
str in (DataTypes.CHAR, DataTypes.INTEGER) # True

bool in (OtherTypes.CHAR, OtherTypes.BOOLEAN)  # True

DataTypes.choices  # [(<class 'str'>, 'Short string'), (<class 'int'>, 'Integer')]

OtherTypes.choices # [(<class 'str'>, 'Short string'), (<class 'int'>, 'Integer'), (<class 'bool'>, 'Boolean (Either True or False)'), (<class 'float'>, 'Floating point number')]
```